# How I pass argument as generic?

Tags: java, generics

I have:

```
public class<E extends aninterface> AClass{

    public AClass(){
    }

    public void amethod(E element){
        //something
    }

}

public class B implements aninterface{

}
```

in call code:

```
aninterface f = new B();
AClass<B> ac = new AClass<B>();
ac.amethod(f);
```

It say f is type `aninterface` but parameter is type 'E'

I not understand what point of generics if I cannot do this?

Comment: What does this example have to do with generics in the first place? Generics don't allow anything you shouldn't be able to do without them. They just save you some typing. If you rewrite you code without generics, it will not work for obvious reasons.

Comment: Change 'E' to 'aninterface' and it work....

Comment: Yes, it will, and? Maybe you think it should work because f is actually B? Well, that would work in python, ruby or php, but not in java and c#.

Comment: if i have public void method(aninterface obj){} i can pass B b = new B(); or aninterface b = new B() into that method!!!

Comment: Yes, because `B` it extends/implements `aninterface`. Or, to put it another way, `B` IS `aninterface`, plus something else, and can be used wherever `aniterface` is required. The reverse is not true. You can't use `aniterface` when you need `B`.

Comment: `public class<E extends aninterface> AClass` is not valid syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `AClass<B>.amethod()` expects a `B` as the argument.  But you're passing it an `aninterface`.

Comment: but B implements aninterface- dynamic binding?

Comment: @peroni_santo: Indeed. But "dynamic" means "at runtime".  The compiler works with static type information, hence the error message.

Comment: @peroni_santo: a `B` is a `aninterface` but a `aninterface` is not necessarily a `B`

Answer (score 2):

Note that the *reference* `f` is declared to be of type `aninterface`—and *not* of type `B`. Despite the fact that at run time reference `f` points to an instance of type `B`, the compiler is here looking only for alignment between the declared type of the reference `f` and the `B` demanded by `AClass#amethod(E)`.

Perhaps you meant to write this instead?

```
final aninterface f = new B();
final AClass<? super aninterface> ac = new AClass<aninterface>();
ac.amethod(f);
```

Or maybe this instead?

```
final B f = new B();
final AClass<? super B> ac = new AClass<B>();
ac.amethod(f);
```

Again, note that a `B` is an `aninterface`, but not the converse: an `aninterface` is not a `B`. Hence, you cannot supply a reference of type `aninterface` to a method demanding a parameter of type `B`.